# TypeError: 'LinearConstraint' object is not iterable

Tags: python, optimization, linear-algebra

I am trying to run minimize function using LinearConstraint function on a correlation matrix but every time i make any change it shows me that "LinearConstraint' object is not iterable. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Below function is used to calculate. 
corr is a dataframe given in screenshot.
corr=

```
   col1      col2     col3
   1        0.59  0.68 
   0.59  1        0.92
   0.68 0.92  1




from scipy.optimize import minimize, LinearConstraint

A0 = [.3,.4,.3]
bnds = [(1, 1) for i in range(len(A0))]

def test(w):   
    return (w@np.matrix(corr))@w

temp=minimize(test,A0,constraints=(LinearConstraint(np.array([1,1,1]),lb=1.0,ub=1.0), ))
```

I get following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py in _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac, bounds, constraints, maxiter, ftol, iprint, disp, eps, callback, **unknown_options)
    253         try:
--> 254             ctype = con['type'].lower()
    255         except KeyError:

TypeError: 'LinearConstraint' object is not subscriptable

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-331-ce6c477d5282> in <module>
      8     return (w@np.matrix(corr))@w
      9 
---> 10 temp=minimize(test,A0,constraints=(LinearConstraint(np.array([1,1,1]),lb=1.0,ub=1.0), ))

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\_minimize.py in minimize(fun, x0, args, method, jac, hess, hessp, bounds, constraints, tol, callback, options)
    609     elif meth == 'slsqp':
    610         return _minimize_slsqp(fun, x0, args, jac, bounds,
--> 611                                constraints, callback=callback, **options)
    612     elif meth == 'trust-constr':
    613         return _minimize_trustregion_constr(fun, x0, args, jac, hess, hessp,

C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\scipy\optimize\slsqp.py in _minimize_slsqp(func, x0, args, jac, bounds, constraints, maxiter, ftol, iprint, disp, eps, callback, **unknown_options)
    256             raise KeyError('Constraint %d has no type defined.' % ic)
    257         except TypeError:
--> 258             raise TypeError('Constraints must be defined using a '
    259                             'dictionary.')
    260         except AttributeError:

TypeError: Constraints must be defined using a dictionary.
```

Comment: Your code works for me. Please include the complete error message. Also, do not post data as screenshot, but post it as text. Screenshots cannot be copied and pasted into code.

Comment: thanks @DYZ, I have put the error and dataFrame .  I am not sure why does not it work for me?

Comment: Please pass constraints in tuple like `constraints=(LinearConstraint(np.array([1,1,1]),lb=1.0,ub=1.0), )` reference stackoverflow.com/a/52003654

Comment: @JaydeepDevda i get the same error if i make the edits as per your suggestions. Please have a look at edited code as per your suggestion.  Did it work for you?

Comment: Please check opening and closing bracked or refer : stackoverflow.com/a/52003654
`temp=minimize(test,A0,constraints=(LinearConstraint(np.array([1,1,1]),lb=1.0,ub=1.0), ))`

Comment: ran the code using your suggestion w.r.t open and close brackets then error has changed as follows. TypeError: Constraints must be defined using a dictionary.

Comment: Yes, i followed the page stackoverflow.com/a/52003654 but don't really understand how to assign the constraints in a dictionary? error is updated with the new code.

Comment: Sorry no clue about that you can revert changes and errors.